# Get X and Y coordinates of textview

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, coordinates, android-imageview

I'm trying to learn android.
I want to generate `TextView` on `Button` click over the `ImageView` and get their (X,Y) coordinates of when I move it from one position to another on that `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean touching at a point on the screen.
i think the following code can help you do so

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +
                    String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: i want textview's x,y coordinates which i drag on imageview

Answer (score 0):

```
   //I think following code can help you do so
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

        return true;
}
```